Classify singularities of a complex function at infinity with f(1/x)
i am having some trouble classifying the singularities of the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3}$$ I understand it has a pole in $z=0$, but I do not understand why, according to my textbook, it has an essential singuality at infinity. It is my understanding that i should be able to classify singularities at infinity bly classifying the singularties of $f(\frac{1}{x})$ in $z=0$, so in this case $$f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = z^3 \cdot e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$$ which in $z=0$ should have a pole, as the first factor goes to zero but the second factor goes to infinity more rapidly.
I would really appreciate some help in identifying the essential singularity.

Expand the exponential in $f(\frac 1  z)$ to see that there are infinitely many terms in negative powes of $z$.

So the theorem that states that a function has a pole $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)|$= ∞ is not valid in this case?

What is the value of $z^3 \cdot e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$ when $z=\frac {1+i}{2\sqrt {n\pi}}$?

$e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$ does not go to $\infty$ as $z \to 0$. This is true only when $z$ is restricted to real numbers.

Ah that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much
